# C# Display Special Characters in TextBlock

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my Windows Phone application, I take RSS from Internet and I parse XML.
I take out Title and Description from rss, and display them in a TextBlock.

Here I find some problems, the speacial characters are substituted by rhombus contain "?".

> ```
>       /*CONNECTION AND DOWNLOAD RSS*/ 
>         WebClient wc = new WebClient();
>         wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(load_web_news);
>         wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://.../rssFeedNews.asp"));
>         ....
>      /*SAVE RSS*/
>             TextBlock tbTitle = new TextBlock();
>             Run rTitle = new Run();
>             rTitle.Text = rss.Title;
>             Run rDescription = new Run();
>             rDescription.Text = rss.Description;
>             tbTitle.Inlines.Add(rTitle);
>         ....
>        /*PARSING*/  
>     private void load_web_news(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         XElement xmlitems = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
>         List<XElement> elements = xmlitems.Descendants("item").ToList();
>         foreach (XElement rssItem in elements)
>                 {
>                     RSSItem rss = new RSSItem();
>                     rss.Description1 = rssItem.Element("description").Value;
>                     String title = rssItem.Element("title").Value;
> ```

How to display special chars for example "à" "è" "°"  etc... in a WIndows phone app?

Comment: precise encoding for ITALIAN language is  
:  wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebClient is probably not using the right encoding to dowload your rss feed, try setting the Encoding property to the right one (maybe Unicode?):

```
wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
```

or if you know which specific encoding is used :

```
wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("encoding name here") ;
```